# Arrays - using user input

Tags: c++, arrays, rounding, user-input

I am creating a code where we take an array of float and print its contents to the nearest integer - the rounding couldn't be done by a special library. I spent time doing the rounding portion, but I need to have the array's contents come from the keyboard and am trying to figure out ***where*** (at what point) that needs to happen. Can someone please explain where this should go?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int roundIt(float x) 
{
return x + 0.5;
}

void print_integers(float a[], int size)

{
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    cout << roundIt(a[i]) << ' ';

cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
float rounded[]{ 3.1, 4.7, 5, 5.0, 6.1, 6.8, 7.4, 8.5, 9.6 };

print_integers(rounded, size(rounded));
}
```

Comment: Should it not come right where your "input" is coming from right now? As in, where the array is currently defined before it's fed into `print_integers()`?

Comment: I tried there & before the loop - but it still prints the given decimals from below - I am assuming that I need to add the cout somewhere within main? I am going to keep messing around with it - its just driving me crazy cause I am almost there, but not quite. ha ha

Comment: You are really putting yourself at a disadvantage with the array requirement, an std::vector would simplify this immensely.

Comment: I know, unfortunately we have only gone over namespace - and this is the first and only partial chapter we get on arrays, so I need to work with what I've got. I am just stuck on this last part & its driving me crazy since this is really the only trouble I have had in C++ - probably just overthinking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. To have more flexible application you need to create dynamic array of floats. After that use it and when array is not needed anymore you need to deallocate memory which is occupied by size of array which contains floats. Here is some [source](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) to learn more about dynamic memory.

1. std::cin ([cin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/)) is object which represents standard input stream. With this object you can save input from user (there are also another options how to store user input but for this case it is sufficiently)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int roundIt(float x)
{
    return x + 0.5;
}

void print_integers(float a[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << roundIt(a[i]) << ' ';

     cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   // float rounded[]{ 3.1, 4.7, 5, 5.0, 6.1, 6.8, 7.4, 8.5, 9.6 };
   int sizeOfArray;

   cout<< "Enter number of elements which will be rounded :" << endl;
   cin>>sizeOfArray;

   float* arrElements = new float[sizeOfArray];

   cout<< "Enter "<< sizeOfArray << " elements"<< endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
   {
      cin>>arrElements[i];
   }

   print_integers(arrElements, sizeOfArray);
 
   delete [] arrElements;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  but I think this is a little more complicated than I think that I need it.  When I input decimals it asks for 6 elements, then 5 (whilst counting and not rounding), ...and so on.  I need to take an array of any size (named size) and just print the rounded integers

Comment: I was able to get it to "technically" working by declaring the array a little different - thank you!